# Laravel cache null error

Tags: laravel, caching, null

I'm using File Cache in Laravel 5.3. Everything works fine. After few days in production I have many errors in my laravel.log that WHERE was called on NULL value (from cache). Why is this happening? Every time I open page everything works fine without errors. Can this be caused because of bots accessing my page? I have not idea what I'm doing wrong...

CacheServiceProvider.php

```
// insert settings into cache
Cache::add('settings', Settings::with('langs')->get(), env('CACHE_TIMEOUT'));
```

Helpers.php

```
$value = Cache::get('settings')->where('name', $name)->first()->value;
```

I tried to use conditions if cache value exists then use it but it's really anoying to put it everywhere. And what if value doesn't exists? Should I call database query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Helpers.php I would suggest you using:

```
$settings = Cache::remember('settings', env('CACHE_TIMEOUT'), function() { 
      return Settings::with('langs')->get();
});
$value = !empty($settings) ? $settings->where('name', $name)->first()->value : null;
```

Remove what you have in CacheServiceProvider.php because this code will fire once when it is needed to get data and cache it for next time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: ok just to be sure... everywhere I use values from Cache I should put Cache::remember... ? There will be callback to put them into cache

Comment: Yeah, at least that how I use it and I haven't had problems, it means you reduce places you have to set cache too

Comment: You mean to define all cache variables at the beginning of Helpers.php? Is it loaded first? Because my queries are quite long so defining this every time cache is used would be really annoying :)

Comment: No no you can define wherever you want and whenever you want with remember, once you used it once its gonna cache it and next time remember is called just gonna load from cache

Comment: If I understood it:
- every time I want to access cache value I should get it with Cache::remember
- it should include return query if this value isn't in cache

As I mentioned before I have really long queries for values in cache. Thats really bad idea to define the same queries everywhere I use cache value...

Comment: Why don't you have a helper functions for cache then? Or defined function in models etc.